# combining the information of several dataframes in boxplot

Tags: python

I would like to generalize the problem raised by little in the post [combining the information of two dataframes in boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087467/combining-the-information-of-two-dataframes-in-boxplot)

I have 20 files (my personnal running records), and I would like to display the evolution of my heart rate using boxplot.

so my 20 df look like:

```
time_sec     Hears Rate
0            74
1            74
2            75
.            .
N            145
```

and of course the duration of my activity is not exaltly the same

the goal is to have 20 boxplot on the same figure.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the 20 [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframes as variables `df1, df2, df3 ... df20` you can first store them as a list of dataframes `dfs`. Then try the following approach -

```
#Assuming dfs is the list of pandas data frames

combined = pd.concat([i.set_index('time_sec') for i in dfs], axis=1) #Set index as time and combine them
combined.columns = ['run_'+str(i) for i in range(combined.shape[1])] #rename the columns
combined.boxplot(figsize=(15,5))                                     #Plot
```

[image]

---

#### Complete code with dummy data frames for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

##Creating dummy data

def dummy_data():
    N = np.random.randint(10,30)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'time_sec':list(range(N)),'heart_rate':np.random.randint(70,150,N)})
    return df

dfs = [dummy_data() for i in range(20)] #20 heart_rate datasets

#Assuming dfs is the list of pandas dataframes

combined = pd.concat([i.set_index('time_sec') for i in dfs], axis=1) #Set index as time and combine them
combined.columns = ['run_'+str(i) for i in range(combined.shape[1])] #rename the columns
combined.boxplot(figsize=(15,5))                                     #Plot
```

Comment: perfect, many thanks !